# Is my product too complex to be sold as a configurable product

Tags: category, configurable-product

My product is made up of many different components. This product has 3 significant points of detail.

The first is the width - three options 0.7, 1.2, 1.8

The second is length - four options 1.2, 1.8, 2.4, 3.0

The third is height - ten options 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0, 4.5, 5.0, 5.5, 6.0

The final product is able to be any combination of these three points of detail, is it possible to sell a product with this many variances?

There is a final fourth choice that is footing - two options - fixed or portable - over 90% of the time the portable decision is portable and therefore a minor decision.

Furthermore I would like to add in the possibility of my clients being able to purchase additional components. Such as Components A and F that are based on width (choice 1) or Components B, C, D, E and G  which is based on length (choice 2).

Also if possible I would like my clients to also have the ability to omit components to lower the final price.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: **Why not?**

Long answer:

It never to be "too complex" to set a configurable product. You can set as many attributes as you can.

Ref: https://community.magento.com/t5/Hosting-Performance/Configurable-Product-Limitations/td-p/60322

**BUT**, back to your case, I suggest you to use "Customizable Options"(or "Custom Options" on M1) instead of "Configurable Products".

Furthermore, for "additional components" you specified, I'm afraid you need an extension to do so.

Comment: Thanks PY Yick. This does not really solve my problem. I have decided to separate the products based on the width therefore there only needs to be 2 points of differentiation. However I can't seem to find an option that would allow me to get the correct price. 

This is because the final price depends on both the length and height, there is no flat increase on the base price for length as when the height changes there are increased components that are required, and the longer the components the more expensive.